# No ignorar fichero y su contenido en gitignore al hacer push

Tags: git, git-push, gitignore

tengo una duda con el archivo gitignore. Dentro del fichero "storage" tengo dicho archivo, con el siguiente código.

```
*
!.gitignore
```

Como puedo hacer para que al hacer push no ignore la carpeta currency y todo su contenido?
De antemano muchas gracias.

(imagen fichero)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta no es acerca del push. El push va a incluir a lo que sea que esté en las revisiones. La pregunta es como hacer que eso quede en las revisiones. Con fichero quieres decir "directorio"? Un fichero es un archivo. En todo caso, la respuesta corta es: agrega el directorio, si ya lo estas ignorando, puedes usar ` git add -f` para forzarlo a agregarlo (luego acometes en una revision y luego empujas la revision/rama)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si algo está siendo ignorado, puedes obligar git a agregarlo (para luego acometerlo0) usando `git add -f`

```
git add -f storage/currencies
```

Con eso git debería agregarlo sin problemas. Luego acometes y empujas.

Comment: muchas gracias me ha funcionado